Extract month name from datetime class in R
I have been trying to extract the month name from a column that the class is month.
I tried some things as changing the date format to the following code.
as.strptime(alldf$started_at, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")  

The column name is started_at and df=alldf
Code:
 months(as.Date(alldf$started_at))

I have installed lubridate, but that did not solve this matter.
I would appreciate any kind of support.

Assuming started_at is in date format, in base R, just use format(alldf$started_at, "%B")
